# How can I attach files to code so that the program can run on another computer?

Tags: c#, file, path, filepath

I have a code that contains a path (reads some information from my computer).

For example, the file path is as follows -> "C:\Users...\Desktop\admin\class1\Info\text\file.txt"
My wish is the following.

How can I attach those files to code so that the program can run on another computer?

My program is made in C#.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3314140/how-to-read-embedded-resource-text-file

Comment: Add the file to the solution and set its compile action as content, make the code look for it alongside the exe. Or put it in resources and use it from there